# phpmailer: addEmbeddedImage "background-url"

Tags: php, css, email, background-image, phpmailer

How can I add the background-img from this code-snippet into phpmailer, so that this image is embeded in the mail:

```
<td background="http://www.xxx.de/img.jpg" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background: #ffffff url('http://www.xxx.de/img.jpg')" class="background" height="120" valign="top">xxx</td>
```

**My way:**

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('http://www.xxx.de/img.jpg', 'bgimg1', 'img.jpg');
```

So I replace the urls:

```
<td background="cid:bgimg1" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background: #ffffff url('cid:bgimg1')" class="background" height="120" valign="top">xxx</td>
```

When I receive the Mail I can find bgimg1 in the mail source, but it is not displayed in my mail programm (thunderbird).

If I just make a img-Tag the img is displayed:

```
<img src="cid:bgimg1">
```

Any Ideas how I can get the backround-url into my html-Mail?

Comment: I really wouldn't bother - Outlook doesn't support background images at all, so don't depend on them. If your content IDs match up in the delivered message and it still doesn't display, then it sounds like Thunderbird doesn't do it right either.

Comment: @Synchro: I look at several forums and found older threads (2012 and older) which describe that it will not work. But I didn't find any new threads about this, so I wonder if it's could be possible now.

Comment: Outlook removed support for background images in 2003 when it switched to using Word for HTML rendering. I don't know of any plans to bring back a decent renderer - Outlook versions have been progressively worse ever since.